# Stop .animate()

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to make it so that at `3072px` the button stops moving the img to the right. I think I need to put an `if` statement inside of my animate button. Is that right?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('a.click').click(function() {
        $('img').animate({right : '+=1024'} , 'slow' );
    });
});
```

Comment: The same.If is the easiest of conditional statement.

Comment: Out of curiosity, doesn't increasing `right` actually animate the element towards the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $a = $('a.click');
    $a.on('click', function () {
        $('img').animate({
            right: '+=1024'
        }, {
            step: function (now, fx) {
                if (now >= 3072) {
                    $(fx.elem).stop();
                    // $a.off('click');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82mWF/

Comment: I added at the bottom that img would return to right zero and added an additional 4096 so that it loops its perfect thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `step` option gives you robust animation control:

```
$('a.click').click(function()
{
    var $img = $('img');
    $img.animate({right: '+=1024'},
    {
       duration:'slow',
       step:function() { if ($img.offset().left + $img.width() >= 3072) $(this).stop(); }
    }
});
```

You could extend this approach to checking the boundaries of the window, or another element, or an value that might change while the animation is ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, something like this should be ok.

```
$('a.click').click(function() {
    var $img = $('img');
    if ($img.css('right') <= (3072 - 1024)) {
        $img.animate({right : '+=1024'} , 'slow' );
    }
});
```

`.css('right')` is used to get the computed value of the `right` CSS property.
Also, `$img` is used to cache the jQuery object, to avoid querying the `DOM` two times.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way to loop this so that it goes back to right 0?

Answer (score 0):

In your click handler, first calculate the difference between the current right and `3072`, if it's more than `1024`, then you animate with `+=1024`, if not you just do += whatever the difference is.

Something like:

```
$('a.click').click(function() {
        var $img = $('img');
        var delta = 3072 - $img.css('right');
        var anim = delta > 1024 ? 1024 : delta;
        $img.animate({right : '+=' + anim} , 'slow' );
    }
});
```

Comment: The calculate didnt click till you and alessandro presented that thanks